# What happens if field type/name gets changed when they are referenced in Apex/VF

Tags: apex

what is the best practice to follow if i need to make the modifications like deleting the field which is referenced in Apex.

Comment: if field is referenced in Apex. Then you can't delete the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields referenced in code can't change their data type, API name, or be deleted.

You'll first need to comment out or otherwise replace all references to the field in your code, make the changes to the field, and then uncomment or update the code afterwards.

In reality, this means that if you're deploying from one org to another, you'll need two deployments, plus you'll probably want to back up the data before you start, and possibly restore the data when you're done.

There's no "easy way" to do this, because of the restrictions built into the platform, as a matter of preventing your organization from being broken because the code can't run.

Comment: What is coffee?

Comment: @crop1645 My phone's autocorrection of "code." Seriously.